# How to stop code from sending email when task is marked completed?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code works to send emails 7 days on or before the past due date but in order for it to run, it needs to be assigned to a button within Excel. When the file is opened, I want it to run the code automatically and send emails to those that have upcoming or overdue tasks. It needs to stop sending emails where tasks have been marked "Completed".

```
Sub eMail()
 Dim lRow As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim toDate As Date
 Dim toList As String
 Dim eSubject As String
 Dim eBody As String

     With Application
         .ScreenUpdating = False
         .EnableEvents = False
         .DisplayAlerts = False
     End With

     Sheets(1).Select
     lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

     For i = 2 To lRow

         If Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then

             toDate = Replace(Cells(i, 5), ".", "/")

             If Left(Cells(i, 18), 5) <> "Mail" And toDate - Date <= 7 Then
                 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

                 toList = Cells(i, 7)
                 eSubject = "ACTION ITEM - " & Cells(i, 3) & " is due on " & Cells(i, 5)
                 eBody = "NOTICE for " & Cells(i, 6) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "You have task(s)coming due or ones that are past due. Please complete your tasks as soon as possible, then notify the Quality Administrator when the task is complete."

                 On Error Resume Next
                 With OutMail
                     .To = toList
                     .CC = ""
                     .BCC = ""
                     .Subject = eSubject
                     .Body = eBody
                     .bodyformat = 1
                     '.Display
                     .Display
                 End With

                 On Error GoTo 0
                 Set OutMail = Nothing
                 Set OutApp = Nothing
                 Cells(i, 9) = "Mail Sent " & Date + Time
             End If

         End If

     Next i

     ActiveWorkbook.Save

     With Application
         .ScreenUpdating = True
         .EnableEvents = True
         .DisplayAlerts = True
     End With

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside of your loop, put an if statement... fix the cell reference:

```
For i = 2 To lRow
    If Cells(i,1).value <> "Completed" Then 'could also use Not Cells(i,1).value = "Completed"
        'all of your regular code
    End If
Next i
```

---

**Edit1:**

Update to use your code:

```
For i = 2 To lRow
    If Cells(i,1).value <> "Completed" Then 'OPEN IT HERE
        If Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then
            toDate = Replace(Cells(i, 5), ".", "/")
            If Left(Cells(i, 18), 5) <> "Mail" And toDate - Date <= 7 Then
                Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                toList = Cells(i, 7)
                eSubject = "ACTION ITEM - " & Cells(i, 3) & " is due on " & Cells(i, 5)
                eBody = "NOTICE for " & Cells(i, 6) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "You have task(s)coming due or ones that are past due. Please complete your tasks as soon as possible, then notify the Quality Administrator when the task is complete."
                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .To = toList
                    .CC = ""
                    .BCC = ""
                    .Subject = eSubject
                    .Body = eBody
                    .bodyformat = 1
                    '.Display
                    .Display
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0
                Set OutMail = Nothing
                Set OutApp = Nothing
                Cells(i, 9) = "Mail Sent " & Date + Time
            End If
        End If
    End If 'CLOSE IT HERE
Next i
```

A second way of doing it, with your existing If statement:

```
For i = 2 To lRow
    If Cells(i, 5) <> "" Or Cells(i,1).value <> "Completed" Then
        toDate = Replace(Cells(i, 5), ".", "/")
        If Left(Cells(i, 18), 5) <> "Mail" And toDate - Date <= 7 Then
            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            toList = Cells(i, 7)
            eSubject = "ACTION ITEM - " & Cells(i, 3) & " is due on " & Cells(i, 5)
            eBody = "NOTICE for " & Cells(i, 6) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "You have task(s)coming due or ones that are past due. Please complete your tasks as soon as possible, then notify the Quality Administrator when the task is complete."
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = toList
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = eSubject
                .Body = eBody
                .bodyformat = 1
                '.Display
                .Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
            Set OutApp = Nothing
            Cells(i, 9) = "Mail Sent " & Date + Time
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you Cyril. I added it, hopefully in the correct location but it returns a Compile error: Next without For.  I don't know enough to know what that means.

Comment: @Mary I believe you may have put it in either the wrong location, or put the End If after a loop.  Will update post to show more appropriately where to place the if-statement

Comment: I tried the 2nd way but upon running the code a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch occurred at line: toDate = Replace (Cells (I, 5), ".", "/").  It did open to send the emails but included the ones marked Completed.

Comment: @Mary **A)** did you update where my added code is finding the word "Completed" (i have it looking in column 1 (A))?  **B)** the line for *toDate* was already in your code... did you have that problem previously?  I would guess that your use of .cells without specifying ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NAME") and qualifying references would/count be an issue, as you're working with an outlook window as well.

Comment: I got your first option to work. I accidently hit an erroneous character causing the code to return an error. It works beautifully.  If it is not too much to ask, could you help me with code and placement of the code to run when this file is opened.  I need it to send the emails automatically when opened. I'll change .Display to .Send when everything is finalized.  Can't thank you enough!!!  I truly appreciate your help with this.

Comment: @Mary If you want code to execute when a file is opened, you would put it in the Microsoft Excel Object "ThisWorkbook" and it would be Sub Workbook_Open() to make it run when the workbook is open.

Comment: I will give it a try.  Thanks for all your help with this.

Comment: Beautiful. Works absolutely perfect! I thank you and the team members here who are late on their tasks thank you.

Comment: @Mary If this solved your problem consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of it.